# How to put spaces between items inside the html div?

Tags: html, css

[image: illustration]

What property do I need to add to insert spaces between the server icons in the image?

```
.server-sidebar-div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [gap property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap#flex_layout)

```css
.server-sidebar-div {
  gap: 20px;
}
```